# How to define type of a property based on another property's value

Tags: typescript

```
const targetMap = {
  name: "this is a string",
  age: 23,
  isAlive: false
};

type Filter<T> = {
  fieldName: keyof T,
  value: T[fieldName] // <-------------
};

const filter: Filter<typeof testMap> = {
  fieldName: "name",
  value: 123,  // error
  value: false,  // error
  value: "string", // ok
};
```

In the example above if `T` is `typeof targetMap` possible types for the `Filter["value"]` are `string`, `boolean`and `string`; every possible values for the `Filter["fieldName"]` are `"name"` , `"age"` and `"isAlive"`.

This is doable but what I want is when I set `"fieldName"` to `"age"`, type of value must be `number` or for `"name"` must be `string`.

Is this possible in Typescript? (Or are there any discussions about this that may be helpful?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening an issue on Github(https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36444) I found out we can use something like this:

```
type Filter<T> = { [K in keyof T]: {
    fieldName: K;
    operator: "like" | "equal" | "notLike" | "notEqual",
    value: T[K]
} }[keyof T]
```

and it works!

Answer (score 2):

Add a second generic parameter `K` with the name of the key use:

```
const targetMap = {
  name: "this is a string",
  age: 23,
  isAlive: false
};

type Filter<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  fieldName: K,
  value: T[K]
};

const filter: Filter<typeof targetMap, 'name'> = {
  fieldName: "name",
  value: "...",  
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCGAnA5gUygWXgBxgXhgG8AoGGMeAW1QC4YAiKACwEsIY2Z4ZpEWxk9ADSkuaOgCYAzCLJsAggBsWAN1owAZvEURUxAL4BuYsSgBPbKhgAxFoqipEAHgAqQmAGkYqAB4OwACbsANaoZiAaMC4AfPhEohosqIoBAHJU6h6yMCraAK7qLgDaHgC6BsbEoJCwifaOdLb1zuaWEXBIaJg47gDkFNS9sQQkZInJaRl09AOowqK5igXTAHRrwmQVQA)

Comment: can K be inferred from fieldName?

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve the result we need to define the field key property. Consider:

```
const targetMap = {
  name: "this is a string",
  age: 23,
  isAlive: false
};

type Filter<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  fieldName: K,
  value: T[K]
};

const filter: Filter<typeof targetMap, 'name'> = {
  fieldName: "name", // only possible value is "name"
  value: 'John', // only possible value is value of type string
};
```

If we want to infer the key without using generic types and infer it by value, we can do so by value constructor function. This is the only way how we can take the type from the value which I know. Consider:

```
type Filter<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  fieldName: K,
  value: T[K]
};

const createFilter = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, fieldName: K, value: T[K]): Filter<T,K> => ({
    fieldName,
    value,
})
 // all arguments are type safe and checked
const filter = createFilter(targetMap, 'name', 'John');
```

Using value constructor allows us to create dependencies between arguments, so type `K` is inferred from `fieldName` argument, and `value` argument is narrowed to `T[K]`. Take a look that our function returns `Filter<T,K>` so fully correct object which match the wanted type.

Comment: can K be inferred from fieldName?

Comment: @Sahandevs take a look now